# Running in memory store with Django

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I am looking for a way to store IP/Port information with Django and I am wondering of the best approach to do this.

The structure looks something like:

```
service["Service-1"] = "192.168.0.1, 81"
service["Service-2"] = "192.168.0.2, 82"
service["Service-3"] = "192.168.0.3, 83"
```

So far I have thought of the following approaches:

1. Store a dictionary in memory
2. Create a database and update it periodically with information
3. Run a separate process and have it return a dictionary via RPC.

I think the first approach is the simplest but I don't know where I would create and maintain the dictionary object because I don't see something like a main function in Django other than manage.py. If I had to maintain this dictionary object for the lifetime of the server, where would be the best place to create the object?

The other two approaches I would like to avoid since they are more of a workaround if I cannot get the first approach to work.

EDIT: This information must be updated while the environment is running (every 5 seconds or so).

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would depend on how frequently this information gets updated. If this is something that is set once per environment and not really updated while the server is running, I would just suggest to stick it into local_settings.py and just import from it in your settings.py.

If this does change while the server is running or is more dynamic, I would say to use an external system for management of this.

Comment: I had forgotten to mention that yes it is dynamic and must be updated while the server is running.

Comment: if it doesn't get updated frequently, you can probably just create a model and track it in the DB. Hard to say without you mentioning your particular use case and performance requirements.